# Iteration notation

Tags: notation, index-notation

I would like to use a non-algorithmic notation to denote an iteration  that stores the scalar values of all summations say, for $p=1,\dotsc,3$ in a vector $v$.

This is the general notation:
 $\sum_{j=1}^{p}a_{j}=a_1+a_2+\dotsb+a_p$, consider $a\in \mathbb{R}$, and then:
\begin{align}
v_1&=\sum_{j=1}^{1}a_{j}=a_1 \\
v_2&=\sum_{j=1}^{2}a_{j}=a_1+a_2 \\
v_3&=\sum_{j=1}^{3}a_{j}=a_1+a_2+a_3 \\
\end{align}

So that I get $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)^T$. I think that $v_p=\sum_{j=1}^{p}a_{j}$ will not suffice and it is not clear. What I should use?

Comment: Why do you think $\sum_{j=1}^p a_j$ would not be fine? For me, it would be clear ... The only thing that I would do is to change $v$ into $S$ as in "sum", but that's only a matter of preference.

Comment: Using a subscript would be possible $S_p=\sum_{j=1}^{p}a_{j}$? Do you mean like this? Thank you,

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I think that form is, in my opinion, as clear as it can be.

Comment: Personally, I see nothing wrong with $v_p = \sum_{j=1}^{p} a_j$.  You can then write $$\vec{v} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} v_j e_j, $$ where $e_j$ is the $j$-th standard basis vector.